# Object-Oriented Help ~ Searching

Tags: java

I'm new to OO. I've just started programming in Java for my university course.

I have a problem:
I have a method within the Club class to search for a member's name (or part of a name, according to my worksheet.
I have a class that tests this without me having to manually create objects from the Club class (I'm using BlueJ).

Here's the search method:

```
public void searchMember(String name){
    i=0;
    found = false;

    while( i < members.size() && !found ){
        if(members.contains( name )){
            found = true;
        }else{
            i++;
        }
    }

    if(found == true){
        System.out.println(members.get(i));
    }else{
        System.out.println("Och Naw ... Member not found.");
    }
}
```

And here is the testing class code:

```
public void demo()
{
    club = new Club();
    club.join(new Membership("Gordy Broon", 1, 1972));
    club.join(new Membership("Eck Salmon", 9, 1965));
    club.join(new Membership("Davie Caramel", 5, 1960));

   System.out.println("Now doing some searching: ");
   club.searchMember( "mon" );
   System.out.println(" ");

   System.out.println("And some more searching: ");
   club.searchMember("moon");
   System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Can someone explain to me why when searching for "mon" the result is not found?

To my understanding this should work.

I am new so ANY help and explanation would be amazing ^_^
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me all your class code please. Just to see what is members. Also do you know what are iterators (just fto write you a proper answer)

Comment: In your loop you are invoking `if(members.contains( name )){` and based on it you are either incrementing `i` or setting `found` to true, but I don't see how `members.contains` is using `i`. Maybe you need to add something like `members.get(i).contains(name)`?

Comment: members is a field at the top of the Club class.     ArrayList<Membership> members;

Comment: Also code like `if(found == true)` is considered as bad practice because it is very easy to make mistake like `if(found = true)` where instead of comparing (`==`) you are assigning (`=`) `true` to `found` variable. So instead of `if(found == true)` simply use `if(found)` or instead of `if(found != true)` or `if(found==false)` use `if(!found)`.

Comment: @Pshemo yeah, I tried that but an error occurs: cannot find symbol - method members(int)

Comment: Yeah, you're right on the bad practise thing. Will work on it :)

Comment: It is not `members(int)` but `members.get(i)`. This method will return element stored at position `i`. Since returned element would be probably instance of `Membership` you will also need to use method which will return name of person like `members.get(i).getName().contains(searchedName)`.

Comment: Anyway my comments are only guesses. If you want to get real answer we would need to see some code which would let us reproduce your problem, so consider [edit]ting your question.

Comment: Okay I'll supply Pastebin links.
Membership Class: [link](http://pastebin.com/pJpRAYDL)
Club Class: [link](http://pastebin.com/rqsWgTGK)
Testing Class: [link](http://pastebin.com/EzV3rhsj)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson While I agree with tag removal edit I don't see it as duplicate since OP is not trying to compare strings with `==` instead of `equals`. In fact OP is using `contains` which seems like correct choice.

Comment: I believe I'm expected to use .contains
But to my understanding, I feel like .contains compares Strings only (or am I misunderstanding?)

Comment: There are two different `contains`: The one on Collection (including lists) finds matching (identical) objects; the one on String finds matching substrings.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson This question IS NOT a duplicate of that one. This has to do with using Collection.contains to try to find an object that is not a String, but is "known by" a string (has a name); that question is about confusing `==` with `equals`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help :)

Comment: Can someone explain why this question has been -1'd?

Comment: "*Can someone explain why this question has been -1'd?*" I suspect that because your question wasn't clear (you didn't provide at start enough informations about your code which would let us reproduce your problem, which means we had to guess what could go wrong which is rarely effective way of solving problems). Also instead of [edit]ing your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). So you did 3 things to make helping you harder: 1 you posted your full code (instead of SSCCE); 2 as a link (instead of code); 3 in comments (instead of your writing it in question).

Comment: Ohhh sorry, im new haha. Will do better next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that members is a list. So when you do members.contains( name ) it wont work. You beed to do the following members.get(i).getName().contains( name ).

Comment: Error occurs: cannot find symbol - method contains(java.lang.String).  With the ".contains" highlighted.

Comment: Fixed it, now it should work. (edited to members.get(i).getName().contains( name ))

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a String with a Membership. The `contains` method of `List` will go through every item in the list and check whether `"mon".equals(membership)`, but a `Membership` object will presumably never return true that it is equal to some String.

(I am making an assumption about your `Membership` class, that you have not overridden the `equals` method from `java.lang.Object`. It would be possible to override `equals` so that it *does* return true when compared with a String, but there are two problems. One, you are expecting not just a match when they are equal, but a substring match (where "mon" matches "Eck Salmon"), and two, implementing `equals` this way would be a violation of its contract. It is expected that if `a.equals(b)` then `b.equals(a)`, but no `java.lang.String` object is ever going to return true that it is equal to one of your `Membership` objects, and you can't modify `java.lang.String` to make it do that.)

What you want to do is go through the list and check if any of the membership objects have a name that contains "mon". I assume your Membership object has a `getName()` method:

```
for (Membership membership : members) {
    if (membership.getName().contains(name)) {
        System.out.println(membership);
        return;
    }
}
System.out.println("Och Naw ... Member not found.");
```

It is possible to do this a little more tersely in Java 8:

```
Optional<Membership> maybeMember = membership.stream()
        .filter(m -> m.getName().contains(name)).findFirst();
String result = maybeMember.map(m -> m.toString())
        .orElse("Och Naw ... Member not found.");
System.out.println(result);
```

This finds the first item in the list that matches the condition that its name must contain the specified name, and then maps it to a string using its `toString` method, or else uses the default string if no matching item from the list was found.

Comment: Yeah, the Membership class does have getName method. However, when I try this, an error occurs: cannot find symbol - method getName()        And yeah, I understand that the code I had only works when Strings are in the list. It was more me wondering how to get it with objects.

Comment: I've never seen anything this complex :P
My lecturer is expecting me to do this with the For (or something similar) that I have originally.
I've not learned anything as complex as what you have said I could do quite yet haha.
I have given my code as pastebin links in a comment section above if you have the time to look?
Thanks :)

Comment: Well, there's no need to worry about the Java 8 stuff yet. I'm only including that to make my answer as complete and comprehensive as I can.

Comment: Yeah and I appreciate that. :)

Comment: A few other notes, besides what people mentioned above about `found == true` and such: To print a blank line you can just do `System.out.println()`, you don't need `System.out.println(" ")`. You should declare members as `List<Membership>`, not `ArrayList<Membership>`. Program to the interface, not the implementation. That way, if you decide to switch to `LinkedList` later, you only have to change it in one place.

Comment: Thank you! This will likely be valuable information in the future :)  Much appreciated!